# Bash: How to redirect every command's output to a file?

Tags: bash, alias

I often run searches on my source code repo like this:

```
ack -l "foo bar" .
```

The searches can take 10-60 seconds and produce output like this:

```
path/to/file1       
path/to/file2
path/to/file3
```

I frequently use this alias to open all of the files found in vim:

```
alias go='gvim `fc -s` -p'
```

This works OK, but `fc -s` reruns the previous command, which can take seconds or minutes.

---

It would be very useful to append something like this to every command I run interactively:

```
| tee /tmp/lastCommand to all commands.
```

This way, if the output reveals itself to be useful, then I can do something else to it.

Example usage:

Type:

```
find . -type f
```

Which executes the following:

```
find . -type f | tee $lastOutLocation # Where lastOutputLocation=/tmp/lastOutput
```

You could then use something like this, to filter the previous command:

```
lastOut | grep "SomeString" # Where lastOut is an alias to cat $lastOutputLocation
```

**Is there a mechanism I can use to do something like this?**  I don't think that aliases expose this kind of behaviour.

Potential Hurtles:

- Getting something that works with compound commands: `echo 'baz' ; echo 'bar'`
- Figure out how to modify the command the user typed before running it
- Ignore things like interactive input.  Don't want to capture password prompts

---

Possible solutions, I am currently exploring:

- Using TRAP and shopt as in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250792/2650)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to wrap it up in a shell script (like `run`) that would call the quoted command you want to run.  Then you'd `run 'find . -type f'` and the script would execute `find . -type f | tee $lastOutLocation`.  Note that I used quotes to allow multiple commands as you mentioned.

Comment: consider the typescript (`script`) command

Comment: The biggest hurdle would be programs that want access to the terminal and not just to write to stdout. Piping to `tee` (or anything else) wouldn't be compatible with this.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be very useful to append something like this to every command I run interactively:
>
> ```
> | tee /tmp/lastCommand to all commands.
> ```

A potential start might be to use `~/.inputrc` to bind a key. (That's the configuration file for the GNU Readline library.) For example, using the letter, o, as a mnemonic for **o**utput ...

```
Control-o: " | tee /tmp/lastCommand"
```

One could bind to the <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> key, but that action would have unintended effects.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you want to redirect the output of your commands to a file, that can be done by:

```
#command > output_file
Or also #command | output_file
```

The first one changes the output channel so everything it would write to the terminal it'll write to the output_file, and the second one pipe both programs...

Comment: `command | foo` will only work if `foo` is something that can be executed, and it will not write to `foo`.