# Run every bash command through a function, or wrapper

Tags: bash, command, tee

So I want any and every command that I run to be piped to another command, and I tried using a .bashrc function:

```
* () {
    ${@} | [my command]
}
```

So for example, what I really wanted to achieve was a way to store the stdout of the last command you ran in a temporary file, which you can call with another command:

```
* () {
    ${@} | tee /tmp/last_command
}
```

Another way to explain what I want to achieve:
Something like `ALIAS [any_command]='[any_command] | tee /tmp/last_command'`

So here's a practical example of what I would achieve with the `tee` example:

```
$ tail -5 /etc/passwd
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
```

What actually happens when the command is run (but I don't have to write it everytime):

```
$ tail -5 /etc/passwd | tee /tmp/last_command
```

So here's a complete example:

```
$ tail -5 /etc/passwd
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
$ cat /tmp/last_command
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
somethingsomethingsomethingsomething
$ date
Tue Jan 14 13:26:04 EET 2020
$ cat /etc/last_command
Tue Jan 14 13:26:04 EET 2020
```

Comment: You can use a `DEBUG` trap combined with `shopt -s extdebug`. You can also `bind -x` `\C-m` (Enter) to a shell command which modifies `READLINE_LINE` (the current command line, unexpanded). But are you sure that you can't just __use [script(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)__?

Comment: fwiw, anything like you're trying to do will break the commands which act differently when the stdout is not is not a tty: `ls` in a terminal is different from `ls | tee last_command_output`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash isn't quite that flexible, you can run commands/functions before and after each command line - but capturing output in bash alone is non-trivial.

Some problems include:

- writing to a pipe is not the same as writing to a terminal or file (e.g. `ioctl()`, `fseek()`, `fstat()`), many programs detect this (like `man`, and even `ls`). You won't want to use this with an interactive editor, like `vi`.
- special commands like "`time`", pipelines and even shell loops can complicate solutions, and pipelines alter return codes
- you can't easily "hijack" every possible command with an alias, and such an alias would break command line options/arguments because `alias` only *lexically* replaces the command
- you can't just (over)write a single file, i.e. is there a race when you issue a command to inspect the last output?
- if you want to capture `stdout` and `stderr` you can have an interleaving problem
- if you use a pipe, remember bash creates subshells when there are pipes, and certain other redirections, one immediate side effect is for variable assignment: these be assigned in a subshell instead (and then thrown away, leaving it unchanged in your current shell). "`.`" (`source`) and `exit` are similarly affected. (In the option below using readline, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> can be used to run such commands.)

This is (roughly) what I use for a similar problem, functions called `+`, `++` etc. so I can prefix just the commands for which I want to capture/process the output of, e.g. to the X selection or clipboard:

```
function +() (
  set -f  # no double expand
  eval "$@" | tee >( tr -s "\n" " " | xclip )
  return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}  # real rc
)
```

e.g. `+ find /tmp -name "*.pdf" -mtime -30`
It's imperfect, but mostly does what I need.

Above, @mosvy recommends `script`, this creates a new tty (terminal) in which a program is run which sidesteps all these problems. It writes all output to the parent tty but also records it to a file. It records either an entire session, or a single command, so you still have the problem of how to automagically invoke it.

Instead, use `screen` (because unlike `script` it's possible to interact with and control a running instance) and bash's `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
if [[ "$TERM" -eq "screen" && -n "$STY" ]]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND=screenlog
    SCREENLOG="${HOME}/screenlog"
fi

function screenlog() {
    [[ -n "$STY" ]] && {
        screen -S "$STY" -X log off
        [[ -f "${SCREENLOG:=$HOME/screenlog}" ]] && mv "$SCREENLOG" /tmp/last_command
        screen -S "$STY" -X logfile "$SCREENLOG"
        screen -S "$STY" -X log on
    }
    return 0
}
```

If the above is in your `.bashrc`, you should be able to just start `screen`. The above function is invoked each time bash displays a new command prompt. It checks first that it is running under screen, then it talks to screen to issue commands to stop logging, writes the last output to `/tmp/last_command`, then tells screen to start logging.

One caveat is that because `PROMPT_COMMAND`s are invoked before the prompt is displayed, both the prompt and the command (including edits such as backspace) will appear at the start of the log file. One way around that is to emulate "pre-exec" with a DEBUG trap to run the above instead, like:  [Modify all bash commands through a program before executing them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250713/modify-all-bash-commands-through-a-program-before-executing-them) . 
If you run "interactive" or terminal aware programs (e.g. `man` or `top`) you'll get the terminal control sequences recorded too, useful if you want to playback output (though `script`/`scriptreplay` are better in this respect).

---

Under the hood, bash uses readline, this allows keys to be bound to readline functions, sequences of other keys, or shell functions (but not combinations of the three types). It's relatively easy to do:

```
bind '"\C-e": end-of-line'
bind '"\C-j": accept-line'
bind '"\C-m": "\C-e | tee /tmp/last_command\C-j"'
```

The first two lines are just paranoia to make sure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> are bound as expected (if you have a terminal without `accept-line` bound, you don't have a terminal anymore...). The last line replaces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> (aka "Return") which is usually bound to `accept-line`, with the sequences:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> (end-of-line)
2. `| tee /tmp/last_command` (literal text)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> (accept-line)

This is visible on screen, and in the history, as the issued command itself is changed. The downside is this simple approach isn't "self-aware" and blindly alters every command, even one from history with the change already applied.

Here's a more complicated version which uses a function to modify commands as they are dispatched:

```
bind '"\C-e": end-of-line'
bind '"\C-j": accept-line'
bind -x '"\e\C-a": _recorder'

function _record() {
    tee /tmp/this_command
    [[ -f /tmp/this_command ]] && mv /tmp/this_command /tmp/last_command
}

function _recorder() {
    local text="| _record"
    [[ -z "${READLINE_LINE}" ]] && return 0
    [[ "$READLINE_LINE" =~ "${text}"$ ]] || READLINE_LINE+=" $text"
    return 0
}
bind '"\C-m": "\C-e\e\C-a\C-j"'
```

Step 2 is replaced by a bash function `_recorder`, bound to <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> (which you don't need to type, it just needs to be bound to a keystroke because a macro can contain only keystokes).

This function can be arbitrarily smart, here it handles the output file race,  and checks that the pipe isn't already present before altering the input line. You could also wrap the entire command line in a subshell if other redirections are present (though you'll quickly find parsing bash command lines in bash to be, ehm, complicated).

You could further(!) compound the hackery by fixing the history on the fly:

```
function myprompt() {
    local _seq _cmdline
    local text="| _record"
    read _seq _cmdline < <(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1)  # previous command
    [[ "${_cmdline}" =~ (.*)" ${text}"$ ]] && {
        _cmdline="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        history -d $_seq        # delete entry
        history -s "$_cmdline"  # restore original
    }
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=myprompt
```

The readline approach has a further non-trivial flaw: non-simple commands which can normally be entered over multiple lines are broken by this approach, e.g. (`while`, `for`).

Comment: Thanks, this basically answers everything, and then some :D. I did know about and use both script and screen, but I also wanted to see if I could do it myself, in an attempt at learn-as-you-go kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Would - in lieu of "after every command" - "before the next prompt" suffice? Consider (in `bash`) the

> ```
>    PROMPT_COMMAND
>           If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
> ```

(`man bash`) help?

Comment: But if it's executed prior to a command, then the output of the command would not be caught, as in my example using tee.

Comment: If it's executed after a command, the command's output  is long gone.

Comment: Correct, I expressed myself in a bad way. What I actually need is for it to take any command, and run it through ha function, as I described. Something like `ALIAS [any_command]='[any_command] | tee /tmp/last_command'`